# Flutter throws an error when running build or run

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-build, flutter-run

I keep getting this when I try to run or run a flutter project

```
/Users/user1/Projects/projectx/ios/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics/Sources/FBSDK
CoreKit_Basics/FBSDKUserDataStore.m:19:9: fatal error:
'FBSDKUserDataStore.h' file not found
#import "FBSDKUserDataStore.h"
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
note: Removed stale file
'/Users/user1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-axlixevsrpjdqpcqvk
bkkcevsnce/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/wakelock/wakelock.framework'
```

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by an error in one of the dependencies, an update has been released and I was able to run the application.